# multiple emulator clients connected to emulator server

Tags: java, android, sockets, emulation

I am wanting to connect multiple android emulator clients to an android emulator server. I am using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android), i have changed the server a little bit. The code works great when only 1 client is attempting to connect. When i try to connect two clients to the server the second client's messages do not seem to come through.

I was wondering what i need to do to achieve this goal? Do i need to redirect other ports or is there something i am missing in the code?

The logcat reports the following over and over again, it is stuck in the loop. It starts showing this error as soon as the first client is launched:

```
11-25 00:47:46.543: W/System.err(198):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-25 00:47:46.543: W/System.err(198): java.net.BindException: The address is already in use
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socketBindImpl(Native Method)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(OSNetworkSystem.java:107)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:184)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:136)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:87)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at school.cpe434.ClassAidServer.ClassAidServer4Activity$CommsThread.run(ClassAidServer4Activity.java:64)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198): java.net.BindException: The address is already in use
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socketBindImpl(Native Method)
11-25 00:47:46.552: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(OSNetworkSystem.java:107)
11-25 00:47:46.563: W/System.err(198):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:184)
11-25 00:47:46.563: W/System.err(198):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:136)
11-25 00:47:46.563: W/System.err(198):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:87)
11-25 00:47:46.563: W/System.err(198):  at school.cpe434.ClassAidServer.ClassAidServer4Activity$CommsThread.run(ClassAidServer4Activity.java:64)
```

---

Here is the client (same as the other post):

```
public class ClassAidClient4Activity extends Activity {
   private Button bt;
   private TextView tv;
   private Socket socket;
   private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
//   private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.102";
   // AND THAT'S MY DEV'T MACHINE WHERE PACKETS TO
   // PORT 5000 GET REDIRECTED TO THE SERVER EMULATOR'S
   // PORT 6000
   private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      try {
         InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
         socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
      } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      }

      bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
               EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
               String str = et.getText().toString();
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                     new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                     true);
               out.println(str);
               Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               tv.setText("Error1");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               tv.setText("Error2");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               tv.setText("Error3");
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

Here is the server (changed from other post a little):

```
public class ClassAidServer4Activity extends Activity {
   ServerSocket ss = null;
   String mClientMsg = "";
   Thread myCommsThread = null;
   protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
   public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
      this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
      this.myCommsThread.start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         ss.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         switch (msg.what) {
         case MSG_ID:
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(mClientMsg);
            break;
         default:
            break;
         }
         super.handleMessage(msg);
      }
   };
   class CommsThread implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
//         Socket s = null;

         while(true) {
             try {
                 ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );

                 Socket socket = ss.accept();
                 Thread lThread = new Thread(new ListeningThread(socket));
                 lThread.start();

              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }


      }
   }

   class ListeningThread implements Runnable {

       private Socket s = null;

       public ListeningThread(Socket socket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           this.s = socket;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Message m = new Message();
                m.what = MSG_ID;
                try {
                   if (s == null)
                      s = ss.accept();
                   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                   String st = null;
                   st = input.readLine();
                   mClientMsg = st;
                   myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
       }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.

`ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );` needed to be outside the while loop.

If anyone sees any other problem, just let me know. Thanks

```
class CommsThread implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
//         Socket s = null;

        ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );

         while(true) {
             try {


                 Socket socket = ss.accept();
                 Thread lThread = new Thread(new ListeningThread(socket));
                 lThread.start();

              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }


      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a ThreadPool for multiple clients (i.e. different emulators) to connect to a single Server. It works very well.