# Client Server application in android NullPointer error?

Tags: android, client, nullpointerexception, emulation

I am transferring a message from one emulator instance on a machine to another emulator instance on same machine.

A server runs on the machine A. It runs perfectly (I guess)
The client runs ok. But when I click a button to transfer data from client to server I get
Null pointer exception in (scoket,getoutputstream())

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                         new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                         true);
```

I also sometimes get the permission dined error in client

I have done all redirections, and added INTERNET tag in android manifest file too,

I got the server crashing with permission denied error but after I added the Internet allow tag server worked..
But when I added the the same tag to client's manifest file the client crashes

SO am not able to remove the permission denied error by adding the INTERNET tag
At the same time am not able to clear the NULLPOINTER exception

Also the client and local machine have different timezone.
The android emulator doesn't take Local TZ by default.

So I set up the -timezone option and even that doesn't change the timzone zone
AFAIK i guess am doing things right w.r.t to ports and ips.
There is no error when creating socket but only when using the socket.ouputstream?
Are there any firewall problem. ?

I have searched extensively and not sure what the problem is. 
Looking forward to your help.
Thanks.

## EDIT:

I am using the client server Code from here by NickT
[Connecting 2 Emulator instances In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android)
and have modified a little
Am getting the error3 
and when I print the error:

```
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:347)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:618)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:258)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct.onCreate(ClAct.java:40)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-25 18:59:06.185: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 19:00:14.045: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 19:00:14.055: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-25 19:00:14.055: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-25 19:00:14.065: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 19:19:45.285: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 349K, 7% free 6380K/6791K, paused 10ms+2ms
11-25 19:26:27.115: I/dalvikvm(388): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
11-25 19:49:48.055: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 7ms+2ms
11-25 20:19:58.565: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 7ms+2ms
11-25 20:45:27.594: I/dalvikvm(388): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
11-25 20:50:09.304: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 7ms+3ms
11-25 21:20:19.785: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 4ms+2ms
11-25 21:50:29.924: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 8ms+5ms
11-25 22:20:40.565: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 8ms+3ms
11-25 22:50:50.675: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 7ms+2ms
11-25 23:21:00.474: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 5ms+4ms
11-25 23:51:10.485: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 11ms+3ms
11-26 00:21:20.725: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 8ms+2ms
11-26 00:51:30.835: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 8ms+3ms
11-26 01:21:41.254: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 419K, 8% free 6378K/6919K, paused 12ms+4ms
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:27.275: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:27.285: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:27.285: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:27.285: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:27.285: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:27.295: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:27.295: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:27.295: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:32.734: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:32.744: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:32.754: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:32.754: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:32.945: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:32.945: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:32.945: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:32.945: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:32.945: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:32.955: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:33.116: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:33.125: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:33.125: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.125: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:33.125: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:33.125: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:33.155: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.195: D/dalvikvm(388): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 8% free 6382K/6919K, paused 4ms+2ms
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:33.305: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:33.315: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:33.315: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.455: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:33.465: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:33.465: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:33.465: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:33.465: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:33.465: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:33.475: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:48:33.764: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:48:33.774: W/System.err(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:49.035: W/System.err(472): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
11-26 01:50:49.035: W/System.err(472):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:49.035: W/System.err(472):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:347)
11-26 01:50:49.035: W/System.err(472):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:618)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:258)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct.onCreate(ClAct.java:40)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-26 01:50:49.045: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:50:49.055: W/System.err(472):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:50:54.375: E/Client(472):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:54.375: W/System.err(472): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 01:50:54.375: W/System.err(472):  at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
11-26 01:50:54.375: W/System.err(472):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
11-26 01:50:54.375: W/System.err(472):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
11-26 01:50:54.375: W/System.err(472):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 01:50:54.385: W/System.err(472):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the error log please. Also post how socket gets instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception log tells you exactly where the error is:

```
at net.wipp.ece.ClAct$1.onClick(ClAct.java:54)
```

That means that in your ClAct class, in the onClick method, on line 54 something is null. If you set a breakpoint and debug all the way up to that point, you will see that something is null on that line.

Comment: Yes.. Thats the line that i quoted 
Am getting null in " socket.getOutputStream()"
But am not sure whats causing tht error in getoutputstream() ?

Comment: Your INTERNET permission flags must be set on both client and server. Is your socket object null when you debug?

Comment: It most likely is not crashing because you add internet permissions, what is the error of the crash when you add the permission?

Comment: Jack thanks very much . I finally figured out that there a uncaught error . I finally caught it and it as due to the new StrictThread policy on the UI thread. So i just reverted back to older sdk and now it works. The new thread policy was enforced from Android 3