# android programming how to send and receives a file (in emulator)?

Tags: android, ftp, android-emulator

I need the server to send a filename to client and a client to receive the filename and send the file to server. This should happen continuusly whenever the server requests a file. 
Can someone please point to a good two way communication client server program ? The program i  use is from

[Connecting 2 Emulator instances In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android)

I have modified this code such that client sends hard-coded file from client to server. But I need to modify it to send and receive at both the ends(i.e send the requested file). I am  bit messed up going about it and need help to move on.

I am very new to android programming and needs help desperately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a very significant example program but your lack of personal research is what's holding you back. There are already existing programs to do this for you.

Comment: yea.. But this is part of a bigger application and I tried changing and got messed up.. Thats why if some one could point at something i can start again . I am not asking for a program .. but just a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HTTP Server, there are a couple out there I found with one [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20http%20server). It will allow you to use HTTP which is more robust than a simple socket protocol. You may also have to implement a file browser, try using the [File API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) with a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).