# What is the best way to test a P2P application in Android?

Tags: java, android, p2p

I am trying to create a P2P network of android(V3.2) devices to share information like news,updates between them .

Been trying [TomP2P](http://tomp2p.net/doc/advanced/android.html), how ever am not able to find a solution of how to debug these . For example I would like to run two different instances either in emulator or AVD Manager and to get these messages shared in between them.

Have also tried port forwarding,how ever yet to see how to communicate between these two emulators.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup port redirection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android). Lets assume you have two emulators listening on the default port 5554 and 5556:

Since TomP2P uses UDP and TCP, you need to redirect both on both emulators:

```
    telnet localhost 5554
    redir add udp:5001:4001
    redir add tcp:5001:4001
```

and

```
    telnet localhost 5556
    redir add udp:6001:4001
    redir add tcp:6001:4001
```

This will redirect from your developer machine (10.0.2.2) port 6001 resp. 5001 to your Android device to port 4001. To connect from one Android device to an other Android device you have to use the IP 10.0.2.2! Further details with a working example can be found on the [TomP2P documentation site](http://tomp2p.net/doc/advanced/android.html).