# Android chat working on emulators with redir

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator

I have read tons of this same advices about connecting two emulators using telnet. For example this one: [Connecting 2 Emulator instances In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android/4738690#4738690)

I've made all as it is said and nothing works. I have got server app on emulator 5554 and client app on emulator 5556. They are using ports 6000 server app and 5000 client app. What I want is to communicate when this two emulators are open - in both ways.

At the beginning server app shows her ip, and in client app user have to write this ip. That is whole configuration.

As in mentioned post was said I've written `redir add tcp:5000:6000` but nothing works. Also when I write `redir add tcp:6000:5000` nothing happen. Those apps don't hear each other. However if server is on other device than everything works fine.

Maybe it is stupid question but can someone guide me through this, because I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post your code?